# Can I change color of image pixels based on background pixel color in web page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, colors

I would like to create an html element with a given background colour, and some text. I would then like to place an image in this div, and where the image overlaps with the text replace the color of the pixels with some other colour. The image below demonstrates the effect I would like to achieve, if we imagine the image is the black blob. However, in real life I want partial overlap of letters to be possible with the same effect (i.e. I don't want to just change the font colour where it overlaps.)

[image: overlap change effect image]

Is this possible, and if so, how?

You can assume the image is a single block colour, and that I know the exact colour as I am creating the image. You may use any web technologies, and the image will be created as a vector image so can be any format, including svg.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the browser support is nowdays but you could try this:
http://css-tricks.com/image-under-text/

Comment: This looks promising thanks, it will take a while to figure out if I can actually do what I want using this though!